# What is the BigO time complexity of modifying a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, big-o

What is the runtime of modifying a std::string? I assume constant time or is there something more going on under the hood in the string class?

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str = "Hello World!"
  str[1] =  'a';  // <--- what is the runtime?
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Its complexity is O( 1 ).

Comment: Instead of down voting the question, it would be helpful to point out where that information is stored such that people can look it up themselves easily in the future. Just saying. Now I know, thanks to the answer of Blaze.

Comment: I did not down-vote your question.

Comment: You might want to add "*as a function of the string length*" and/or "*as a function of the index*" to make clear which one you are asking about. Also you should make clear that you are asking about substitution of individual characters. The answer changes when you are erasing/adding a character. (I am not the downvoter either, though.)

Comment: @uneven_mark I personally would qualify the question as OK even without that addition. Looks to me like a 'just for fun' down-vote.

Comment: @Matt Most operations complexity is mandated by the standard. You can also view it on cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at and (or similar resources like cplusplus.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, it's constant. According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/):

> Complexity
>
> Constant.

For C++11 that is, it's unspecified for C++98, but I wouldn't assume that an implenetation with non-constant `std::string::operator[]` would be commonplace.

Comment: Back in 2005 copy-on-write std::string was commonplace. GCC 3.4 had it too IIRC.

Comment: Oh wow, that's interesting. Thanks for sharing this tidbit. Was there any particular reason to not have mutable strings back then?

Comment: '*not to have mutable strings*' – but they *were* mutable... Just instead of copying string data immediately, strings with same content might have shared it. Would have needed reference counting, and a string would create the copy of the data not earlier than when it gets modified (*and* reference count is > 1, of course...).

Comment: @Blaze COW != immutable

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong term here. What I meant was that the original memory is not being changed as a copy is being modified instead.

Comment: @Blaze Example: `std::string s("hello world"); std::string c(s);` – at this time, `c` hasn't yet copied internal data, but shares common data with `s`. Only when one of both gets modified, that one will create the copy needed, while the other one stays with the original data.

Comment: Ah ok. So it's a performance tradeoff. In that example, `s` could even keep a pointer to the original read-only `"hello world"` char array.

Comment: I'm still confused. c++ strings are immutable, so shouldn't this entire stirng be copied?